# Complicated conundrum with passing information in Java methods

Tags: java, methods, return-type

I've got a problem. Here it is:

A method is called when a "skill" is used in the game. In this case, the skill is tying people up. Success is determined by rolling some dice. The result of that roll then becomes the roll that the person who is tied up must beat in order to break free of their bonds.

However, if the person being tied up can fight back, then they may also roll right then to prevent themselves from being tied up, using a different skill. These rolls are opposed and the person doing the tying must beat the other person's roll.

However, whenever there is an opposed roll, whichever person fails may spend a luck point to redo their roll and attempt to beat it again. Both people involved in an opposed roll can keep doing this until they run out of points.

This is all fine and dandy, but the method for an opposing roll only returns who won. It does **not** return the raw roll, which we need to know to determine whether the person being tied up can break free of it later.

```
    boolean success = false;
    Ability C = target.reallyFindAbility("Skill_Cleverness");
    final int fettRoll = roll(mob); //Cannot use opposedCheck because we need the raw roll.
    if((ez)||(fettRoll>C.roll(target)))
    {
            fetteringDC = fettRoll;
```

Here's one solution: We make the roll in the first place, save it, and then pass it to the method to determine whether or not they succeed. But there's a problem with that: if they fail and start re-rolling, that roll is no longer valid. It needs to be updated, but it can't be; the method only returns whether they won.

The luck point system uses recursion. It can't be recreated within the method that uses the skill in the first place because that's only one method and it does a lot of other things; recursing it would be wasteful and might have unintended consequences if any other parts of the program count how many times that skill is used.

```
/**
 * Returns whether the given mob passes their proficiency check in this skill
 * at this time, by rolling a 3d6 plus their ranks in the skill (proficiency)
 * against the Difficulty Check provided. 0 or lower is a failure.
 * @see com.planet_ink.coffee_mud.Abilities.interfaces.Ability#proficiency()
 * @see com.planet_ink.coffee_mud.Abilities.interfaces.Ability#proficiencyCheck(MOB, int)
 * @param mob the mob whose proficiency to check
 * @param target the mob opposing
 * @param ID the name of the skill opposing
 * @return the amount by which the mob passed or failed
 */
@Override
public int opposedCheck(MOB mob, MOB target, String ID)
{
    if((mob!=null)&&(target!=null)&&CMSecurity.isAllowed(mob,mob.location(),CMSecurity.SecFlag.SUPERSKILL)&&!CMSecurity.isAllowed(target,target.location(),CMSecurity.SecFlag.SUPERSKILL))
       return 10;
    else if((mob!=null)&&(target!=null)&&!CMSecurity.isAllowed(mob,mob.location(),CMSecurity.SecFlag.SUPERSKILL)&&CMSecurity.isAllowed(target,target.location(),CMSecurity.SecFlag.SUPERSKILL))
       return -10;

    Ability O = target.fetchAbility(ID);
    if(O==null)
        O = CMClass.findAbility(ID);
    if(O==null)
        return 10;
    final int skillRoll = roll(mob);
    final int oppRoll = O.roll(target);
    final boolean success = (skillRoll>oppRoll);
    if((!success)&&(mob!=null)&&(!mob.isMonster())&&(mob.playerStats().luckPoints()>0)&&(mob.playerStats().getAutoLuck(PlayerStats.LUCK_SKILLREROLL)>=CMLib.dice().rollPercentage()))
    {
        mob.playerStats().setLuck(mob.playerStats().luckPoints()-1);
        return opposedCheck(mob, target, ID);
    }
    if((success)&&(target!=null)&&(!target.isMonster())&&(target.playerStats().luckPoints()>0)&&(target.playerStats().getAutoLuck(PlayerStats.LUCK_SKILLREROLL)>=CMLib.dice().rollPercentage()))
    {
        target.playerStats().setLuck(target.playerStats().luckPoints()-1);
        return opposedCheck(mob, target, ID);
    }
    return skillRoll-oppRoll;
}
```

I can't think of any elegant solution to this problem. The only fix that would satisfy every requirement would be to have the opposed roll pass back an untyped Vector containing the roll, whether they won or not, etc., and that not only seems sloppy but also poses a problem because this is a *very specific* use scenario and I would have to go back and change it for every other instance where I used that method that did not require that much detail from it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: We are programmers, we can't read this much text.

Comment: Bad Question, Show us what you've done so far, what the issue is and what the expected output is. Also i'm not reading that wall!

Comment: @Scary Wombat you **can**, i can't :D

Comment: @codeCompiler77 and we can't write either.

Comment: @Scary Wombat haha :) it's all good mate, i bit my tongue today. Happens to the best of us, then the rest of us!

Comment: If you can't read the wall you won't understand the nuance of the problem. There are 4 competing factors at work, and considering the size of the code base it'd take more space to show what I've done so far than to simply explain it in text. Plus, I don't know what the expected output *should be*. I'm asking for design help.

Comment: @user1796160 i read your wall, TL;DR i get a boolean true false value but the value of the roll. **Solution:** Return the value of the roll and evaluate state afterwards. The problem starts with the fact that you're missing that one value. Fix the issue at the root :) The other issue with this is that you're asking for nuance, how can a roll fail? We don't understand, nor did you explain that. If a roll fails. Just keep it in a loop until the roll succeeds or they run out of re-rolls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send back a Pair or something similar that will hold both a boolean, to indicate who won, and two integers, to indicate the rolls.

You say "I would have to go back and change it for every other instance where I used that method that did not require that much detail from it." This can easily be solved by creating a new method in order to handle this specific use case.

In addition, your luck based system should probably use a Stack instead of recursion to prevent overflow if both players have a ton of luck points.

Comment: Yeah, right now it seems like the most elegant way to do it would be to fob off the actual rolling to a new, separate method and have the old method only return success.

Comment: I agree now that I understand the full issue. Make a sibling to `opposedCheck` that returns a Pair with the result and the necessary roll. To avoid code duplication, you could change `opposedCheck` to call the new method and just return the success boolean.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are trying to do can be accomplished by a bit of abstraction. Refactor your current 'skill' method into a couple methods meeting these general processes:

- Get/Generate Attack Roll
- Get/Generate Defense Roll
- Did Attack Roll Win (given Roll attack, Roll defense)

And importantly,

- Determine if Attack will use a luck point to reroll
- Determine if Defense will use a luck point to reroll

Therefore, you have one method that ONLY does the generation of an attack roll, one method that ONLY does the generation of a defense roll, and one method that ONLY does the calculation of which roll won. It doesn't matter how the intermediate data is stored so long as it works as intended.

The important part is now with the refactor, you can have a loop that does something like the following pseudocode:

```
int attack = getAttackRoll();
int defense = getDefenseRoll();
boolean success;
while(true) {
    success = attackWins(attack, defense);
    if (success) {
        if (repeatDefense()) { // if defense wants to use a luck point
            defense = getDefenseRoll(); // regenerate defense roll
        } else break; // otherwise exit as success=true
    } else {
        if (repeatAttack()) { // if attack wants to use a luck point
            attack = getAttackRoll(); // regenerate attack roll
        } else break; // otherwise exit as success=false
    }
}
return success;
```

(I do not necessarily recommend implementing the loop as such. This is an example only.)

The key point here is that we can check each condition that effects the outcome separately without side effects. `repeatDefense()` queries the defender if they want to use a luck point to re-roll their defense (if they have luck points to spare, of course). You could also pass it the defense roll and/or attack roll to show them what was rolled. The same for `repeatAttack()`, but from the other side of the problem.

Another key is that this method outlined here (call it `getResultAfterLuck()`) calls single-level luck determiners. The `repeatDefense()` `repeatAttack()` only handle a SINGLE occurrence of luck use, allowing the result calculator to handle the rest, including querying again if the roll didn't succeed again. If you want to always us the highest rather than most recent, just introduce a temporary variable and use something like Math.max(int, int).

The goal here is to get [Pure Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) to query state given rolls, so you can re-roll freely.

This could then be wrapped up in a nice `getResultAfterLuck` method for ease of use. Additionally, the only part that will ever be repeated is what needs to.

If you need to monitor how many times a skill is used, just make sure to fire the event outside of the processing loop and you should be fine.

Upon clarification: Since you actually need both the roll and the success, returning a Pair in a sibling method is your best bet, as q&a suggested first.

Comment: This is already how my code is structured, in fact! The problem is that didAttackRollWin() returns a boolean value *and* handles the luck rerolling. I can structure the code around taking the raw roll from getAttackRoll() but then it won't use luck points. If I make a separate method to return the roll after luck rerolling, then it won't return whether or not they won. I cannot compare the two rolls (necessary for luck) return the result AND return one of the rolls.

Comment: The key point here is the loop: I've created `repeatDefense()` and `repeatAttack()` to decide whether to use / track luck points. In reality there would/should be some objects here to manage state, but this logical pseudocode gets the point across. I'll edit the question to make the luck handling clearer, though.

Comment: Hmmm. I think I understand what you're saying but it's basically what I was trying to avoid; repeating myself by implementing luck handling separately into the skill as well as into the normal method for other skills that don't require the result. Plus, wouldn't getResultAfterLuck() not return whether or not they won?

Comment: This method would be the `getResultAfterLuck()` method. You could also provide a `getResultWithoutLuck()` if you wanted. Both of these would use the same Pure functions as a resource, which are the `getRoll()` and `didWin(roll, roll)` functions. The luck function just would also loop until both users were happy with the outcome (or out of luck).

Comment: Right, that's what I'm saying. This method is getResultAfterLuck(), but the skill needs *both* the result *and* the boolean. I suppose I could pass the result of attackWins() into getResultAfterLuck(boolean) to get it... but wait, wouldn't I also need both rolls? OK, I think I get it; you're suggesting a separate method purely for recursing through the players' luck points that changes the boolean returned by attackWins(). I prefer method overloading, though, so I think I am going to have to go with questioner and answerer's solution.

Comment: If the skill does need the result, you can return a Pair<bool, roll> as with q&a. I guess we tackled the question from different angles :) But to be clear, `getResult` is responsible for rolling in my model, so the skill handler wouldn't roll anything, but rather just call `getResult` to see if the skill succeeded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105077/discussion-between-cad97-and-user1796160).